# Are all nuclei of a given isotope of a given element necessarily identical?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, identical-particles

Consider two nuclei with exactly P protons and N neutrons each.
Is it possible for their nuclei to be different? (e.g., for the "clouds" to be distributed differently?)
By "different" I mean that e.g. neither is a rotation, reflection, or other such inconsequential transformation of the other. Do note that I'm talking about the quantum-mechanical distributions being different, not their measured values at a particular instant.

Furthermore, if it is possible, then is there a terminology for referring to this (similar to how "isotope" refers to different nuclei of the same element), and do such atoms behave differently in either chemical or nuclear reactions?

Intuitively, I find it shocking for the answer to be *false*, but at the same time I don't think I've seen anyone say that it's true, so I would like to understand which is the case, and why.

Comment: See perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_isomer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible for them to be different, and the frequently are. They are called nuclear isomers. They have slightly different masses. One is capable of emitting radiation that the other isn't. And many other differences. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_isomer#Decay_processes

Answer (score 0):

They are not different.

Some molecules are [chiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(chemistry)):  they have the same chemical composition although the two mirror images differ in subtle (but not necessarily unimportant) ways in their chemistry.  The mirror image pairs are called enantiomers.  There is no known property like this in nuclei.

Comment: Thanks a ton! but I can't tell if this contradicts the comment under my question or not... does it?

Comment: if they have the same number of protons and neutrons they are the same.  Individual nuclei may be in different energy states, but that's basically it.  They have the same nuclear or chemical properties.  If you find otherwise please let me know :)